# Inverse of isomorphism between two fields is isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, order-theory, real-numbers

I'm using [this definition](http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math205A/uniqreals.pdf) of isomorphism between two systems satisfying the axioms of Dedekind-complete totally ordered fields to show that its inverse is an isomorphism too. I can be easily proved that it's a bijection and both of morphism properties characteristic to ordered field isomorphisms. I have problem proving the last condition, that $f(a)\,{\preceq}_Y\,f(b){\implies}f^{-1}(f(a))\,{\preceq}_X\,f^{-1}(f(b))$.

We know by the provided definition that ${\forall}a,b\,{\in}\,X:a\,{\preceq}_X\,b{\implies}f(a)\,{\preceq}_Y\,f(b)$. The [usual](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Order_Isomorphism_is_Order_Isomorphism) proof of the condidition mentioned before uses the property $a\,{\preceq}_X\,b{\iff}f(a)\,{\preceq}_Y\,f(b)$, which is indeed often used in definitions of order isomorphisms.

I can't do this, since my source uses a mere ${\implies}$ instead of more convenient ${\iff}$; how can I deduce from my axioms that $a\,{\preceq}_X\,b{\iff}f(a)\,{\preceq}_Y\,f(b)$? If I can't, how to prove that $f(a)\,{\preceq}_Y\,f(b){\implies}f^{-1}(f(a))\,{\preceq}_X\,f^{-1}(f(b))$?

Comment: $x \preceq_Y y \iff (\exists z)(y = x + z^2)$.

Comment: Aside: the definition in that link is that of a "bijective morphism". That turns out to be the same thing as an isomorphism in this case (and a number of other cases), but it's not the same in general. The general meaning of "isomorphism" is "invertible" (and the inverse is a morphism).

Comment: What's the difference, in context of ordered fields (currently the only context I care about)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that your orderings are total.  If $a\not\preceq_X b$, then $b\prec_X a$.  This implies $f(b)\preceq_Y f(a)$ and $f(b)\neq f(a)$ since $f$ is injective, so $f(a)\not\preceq_Y f(b)$.

Answer (score 3):

If the fields are totally ordered then,
if $a \nleq b$ then $b < a$, whence $f(b) \leq f(a)$;
in fact, $f(b) < f(a)$, because $f$ is injective;
then $f(a) \nleq f(b)$.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is that trichotomy partitions everything into three disjoint cases preserved by morphisms:

- $a < b \implies f(a) < f(b)$
- $a = b \implies f(a) = f(b)$
- $a > b \implies f(a) > f(b)$

So having $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ fall into one of the three cases can only happen if $a$ and $b$ are in the same case.